# how do i manipulate a randomly selected vertices in an object in blender python?

Tags: python, blender, vertices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZUQZ.jpg)
I'm using blender 2.79, and i'm having some difficulties in writing my code. here is what i am planning to do.
I'm using a simple plane in this example. i have selected 2 of it's vertices. what i want to do is activate the 2 selected vertices and print it using for loop. this was the code that i used

```
import bpy
import bmesh

p = [i.index for i in bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.active.data).verts if i.select]
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

for g in p:
    bm.select_history.add(bm.verts[g])
    print(bm.select_history.active)
```

as you can see, this is a combined code that i have founded in this site and it was a fail. what i can found was either activating a single vertex or finding an entire vertices if an object. i do not want that, all i need is just to edit the 2 selected vertices. i could not find a code that i can use for a multiple selected vertices. please help me solve this.